# How to add an alias filter to the media view?

Tags: views, media, path-aliases

I have a path alias for my media content provided by pathauto. The media view at 'admin/content/media' shows all the content. I am able to add filter for the media entity name, type, language and other fields but I cannot add a filter for the URL alias.
I was able to add the field 'link to entity' which shows the correct URL (alias). Then I added a exposed combined filter that uses the media link field. However as soon as I try I get an error "col not found" in the view.